# Value Decimal conflict in "Line and Stacked Column Chart" in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence, dashboard

I have a  **Line and Stacked Column Chart** in Power BI. The problem I can not solve is , I want to show the 1 decimal in Line Data Value, but not in Column Value. My chart is this ;

[image]

I click the *Data Labels* in properties and set **1** in the *Value Decimal Places.* Then my chart looks like this ;

[image]

As you can see it is OK for Line value but there is a worthless zero decimal in Column values.

I also try to change the Data Types in Modeling but it is same problem.
Let me know if you have any advices .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit weird, but I was able to do it by recreating the visual. Make sure the data columns are formatted how you want them first and *do not* mess with the `Value decimal places` setting under Data labels or you won't be able to go back to having them different.

[image: Data Labels]

Hopefully, in the future, Microsoft will allow you to set the decimal places for line and column separately under the data label settings.

I've submitted such a suggestion to their ideas site. You should be able to [vote for it](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/34209592-bar-line-combo-chart-separate-decimal-place-set) once it processes and shows up.